# Hyperbolic fixed point of ODE

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose we have a linear autonomous two dimensional ODE:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt} = Ax
\end{equation}
for some matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$. Now we say a system is hyperbolic if the real part of the eigenvalues of $A$ are non-zero. Now wikipedia says the following: 
"Several properties hold about a neighborhood of a hyperbolic point, notably[2]
A stable manifold and an unstable manifold exist"
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_equilibrium_point ]
. But if I take $A=Id$ then all solutions diverge (except $0$ of course). So where is my stable subspace? Or analogue if I take a matrix with only negativ eigenvalues all solutions converge to $0$. Where is my unstable subspace? I dont understand this definition of hyperbolicity. Shouldn't it intuitively mean that one eignvalue is greater $0$ and one smaller $0$? Sorry Im really confused here.

Comment: In the first case your stable manifold is trivial, $\{0\}$, whereas unstable manifold is exactly $\mathbb R^2$. In the second case, the stable manifold is $\mathbb R^2$. In any case, in the hyperbolic situation, the dimension of the stable manifold plus the dimension of the unstable manifold is equal to the dimension of the whole state space.

Comment: Thanks so much, thats exactly what I was missing. Never thought about the trivial cases.